# How to handle a .js extension correctly in bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, bash-scripting

I have the following bash script.

```
while IFS= read -r filename;
  do [[ $(md5 path/to/"$filename-orig") = $(md5 path/to/"$filename") ]] || echo $filename differs;
  done < path/to/list-of-files-to-compare.txt
```

It's supposed to compare two files (by computing their MD5 hash digest) then report if they are different. It gets the files to compare from a list.

The problem is that if the file I am trying to read is at, say,

```
path/to/foo-orig.js
```

the script will look for the file at

```
path/to/foo.js-orig
```

and, obviously, this throws an error and fails.

How do I correct this bug in my script so that I handle the `.js` extension correctly?

Edit

## TL;DR:

Given a string `foo.bar` how can I get `foo-orig.bar`?

Edit2:

I add the `-orig` extension because this project takes a template that's regularly updated by a third party, then I overlay my changes to it. So, I want to keep track of what files they change so I can go back and adapt my code when necessary.

list-of-files-to-compare.txt looks like the following.

list-of-files-to-compare.txt

```
public/assets/images/logos/logo.svg
README.md
src/auth/Auth.js
src/auth/store/actions/login.actions.js
src/auth/store/actions/user.actions.js
src/auth/store/reducers/user.reducer.js
src/firebaseService/firebaseService.js
src/firebaseService/firebaseServiceConfig.js
src/fuse-configs/fuseNavigationConfig.js
src/fuse-configs/fuseRoutesConfig.js
src/index.js
src/main/content/components/ComponentsConfig.js
src/main/content/login/Login.js
src/store.js
src/store/actions/index.js
src/store/reducers/index.js
```

Comment: Why do you add `-orig` in the first place? How does `list-of-files-to-compare.txt` look like?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk: Do the edits help answer your questions?

Answer (score 1):

In `Bash` you could use `Pattern substitution`:

```
while IFS= read -r filename;
do
    echo ${filename/.js/-orig.js}
done < list-of-files-to-compare.txt
```

If you want to be more generic you can first get an extension with `cut` and `rev` like that:

```
$ ext=$(echo public/assets/images/logos/logo.svg | rev | cut -d. -f1  | rev)
$ echo $ext
svg
```

And then replace it with `sed`:

```
$ echo public/assets/images/logos/logo.svg | sed "s,\.${ext}\$,-orig.${ext},"
public/assets/images/logos/logo-orig.svg
```

It would be easier if you appended `.orig` to the filename so that `logo.svg` would become `logo.svg.orig`.